# Sufficient statistics problem

Tags: estimation

$X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are iid $N(0,\theta), 0 < \theta < \infty$

Show $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2$$

is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

My attempt at this is

$S = (X_1^2 + X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2)/n$

$$E[S]= \frac{1}{n} E[X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2]$$

$$E[X^2 - [E(X)]^2 = \operatorname{var}X = \theta$$

$$E[X^2] = \theta = \frac{1}{n}(nt) = t$$

So $S$ is an unbiased estimator of $t$.

$$\operatorname{var}(S) = \frac 1 {n^2} [\operatorname{var} X_1^2 + \operatorname{var} X_2^2 +\cdots+ \operatorname{var}X_n^2]$$

$$\operatorname{Var}(X^2) = E(X^4) - (E[X^2])^2$$

Since $E(X^2) = t$, we must find $E(X^4)$

Using moment generating function for $X$, $e^{\frac{ts^2}{2}}$

Exanding, $s^4 = 1 + (1/2)ts^2 + (1/8)t^2s^4$

coeff of $s^4$ is $t^2/8 = E(X^4/4!)$,

therefore $E(X^4) = 3t^2$

$$\operatorname{var}(X^2)=\frac{3t^2}{2-t^2} = \frac{t^2}2 $$

and $\operatorname{var}(S) = \dfrac{t^2}{2n}$

Is this a sufficient/correct explanation?

Comment: @michaelhardy thanks again for the edits :) looks much nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you write seems irrelevant to the question.

To say that $X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ means that the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ given $X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2$ does not depend on $\theta$.

That is what you need to show.

You might want to use Fisher's factorization theorem: $t(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is sufficient for $\theta$ if the density can be factored as
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n \mid \theta) = g(t(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mid\theta) h(x_1,\ldots,x_n).
$$
where the second factor does not depend on $\theta$.

(In the case of the Poisson distribution the second factor is non-trivial, but for the family of distributions you have here I think you'll get $1$.)

Comment: I guess my attempt was a poor approach... I'm not sure I follow your suggestion of using Fisher's factorization theorem. I'm not familiar with this but will look it up.

Comment: I am struggling with the factorization, particularly what the second factor should be that does not depend on $\theta$

Comment: You have $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (2\pi\theta)^{-n/2} \exp\left( \frac{-(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)}{2\theta} \right) \cdot 1\vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}}.\qquad{}$ Notice the parenthesized short final paragraph of my answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I see. Sorry for overlooking. I was about to follow up with whether I could make $h(x_1, ..., x_n)$ = 1. Thank you.